# TypeError: this._connection.open is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Estou fazendo atividade para aprender sobre o NodeJS e o MongoDB, e durante o projeto, tenho o erro abaixo:

```
TypeError: this._connection.open is not a function
```

Como ainda estou em fase de aprendizado, não consegui entender bem, mas me parece que o problema é com o "open".

O arquivo UsuariosDAO, tem o seguinte código:

```
function UsuariosDAO(connection){
    this._connection = connection();
}

UsuariosDAO.prototype.inserirUsuario = function(usuario){
    this._connection.open( function(err, mongoclient){
        mongoclient.collection("usuarios", function(err, collection){
            collection.insert(usuario);

            mongoclient.close();
        });
    });
}

module.exports = function(){
    return UsuariosDAO;
}
```

E parte do arquivo cadastro.js que aparece relacionado no erro:

```
var connection = application.config.dbConnection;
var UsuariosDAO = new application.app.models.UsuariosDAO(connection);

UsuariosDAO.inserirUsuario(dadosForm);
```

Enfim, qual seria a melhor solução para este problema?

Comment: O erro é claro, a propriedade `open` não é uma função, logo ao chama-la causa essa exceção. Não da pra ajudar mais que isso sem ter o resto do código relacionado a `_connection`

Comment: Poste o código na sua pergunta... Não dá pra ajudar sem ver onde está o erro!

Comment: Acabei de modificar a pergunta, inserindo o código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver após remover a versão mais recente do módulo npm do MongoDB e instalando a versão a seguir:

```
npm install --save mongodb@2.2.9
```